# Conditional INNER JOIN in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a rather complex query that pretty much mimics a test query I have below:

```
SELECT C.*
  FROM Customer C 
       INNER JOIN CustDetail CD ON C.CustomerId = CD.CustomerId
       INNER JOIN Address A ON CD.DetailID = A.DetailID
       INNER JOIN Group G ON C.CustomerId = G.CustomerId   --Join only when C.code = 1
       INNER JOIN GroupDetail D ON G.GroupId = D.DetailId  --Join only when C.code = 1
WHERE G.Active = 1 AND        --Only when C.code = 1
      D.code = '1' AND        --Only when C.code = 1
      C.Id = @customerId
```

I'd like to do `INNER JOIN`s on `Group G` and `GroupDetail D` (and ofcourse not have them in the `WHERE` conditions based on the table column `C.code = 1`

I replaced the `INNER JOIN`s with `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s for both the join conditions, but the result set is not what was expected

How do I conditionally do the JOIN

Comment: How about `INNER JOIN Group G ON C.CustomerId = G.CustomerId AND C.code = 1` ?

Comment: Could you post some sample data, desired results, and how the result set you got with the left joins was "not what was expected"? Knowing what *was* expected can make it a whole lot easier to help you solve your problem.

Comment: How many codes can one customer have, he asks naturally assuming customer.ID is unique in the customers table? if you only want to do teh join if code =1, but don't care if it isn't then a union would be the way I'd go.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I was trying to avoid doing the `UNION` but sounds like it's inevitable. To answer your question, the customer can have a code of 0 or 1. If I do a `C.code = 1` in the join condition, will it ignore it for `C.code = 0`?

Comment: I had a tiny suspicion, looks like @Andew has given you the closest answer to what you want. Given Customer could be 0 or 1, it will work out better for one customer I think. I think I'd be look at normalising and having a CodeZeroCustomers and a CodeOneCustomers table in your position. May be there's some other data only applicable to one or the other you could split out as well. Two value index versus table scan, not a pretty picture that....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT C.*
  FROM Customer C 
       INNER JOIN CustDetail CD ON C.CustomerId = CD.CustomerId
       INNER JOIN Address A ON CD.DetailID = A.DetailID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Group G ON C.CustomerId = G.CustomerId
       LEFT OUTER JOIN GroupDetail D ON G.GroupId = D.DetailId
WHERE ((G.Active = 1 AND C.code = 1) OR G.Active IS NULL) AND
      ((D.code = '1' AND C.code = 1) OR D.code IS NULL) AND
      C.Id = @customerId
```

I'm guessing you didn't include the IS NULL checks before so you never got to see rows where C.code <> 1 ?

You should check for NULL on a field that will never be null. This is almost always 'id', but it's not clear that you have a G.id or a D.id.

Answer (score 0):

This will do a semi-join only when code is 1.

```
SELECT C.*
FROM Customer C 
    INNER JOIN CustDetail CD 
        ON C.CustomerId = CD.CustomerId
    INNER JOIN Address A 
        ON CD.DetailID = A.DetailID
WHERE 
      C.Id = @customerId AND
      (c.code != 1 OR
      EXISTS(
         SELECT NULL
         FROM Group G
            JOIN GroupDetail D ON G.GroupId = D.DetailId
         WHERE
            C.CustomerId = G.CustomerId AND
            G.Active = 1 AND 
            D.code = '1'
      ))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing what you want is just a tighter ON clause, and a compound condition.

```
SELECT C.*
  FROM Customer C 
       INNER JOIN CustDetail CD ON C.CustomerId = CD.CustomerId
       INNER JOIN Address A ON CD.DetailID = A.DetailID
       -- the next two joins happen only when c.code=1
       -- their columns will be null when there is no match.
       LEFT JOIN Group G ON C.CustomerId = G.CustomerId AND C.Code = 1
       LEFT JOIN GroupDetail D ON G.GroupId = D.DetailId AND C.Code = 1
WHERE C.Id = @customerId AND --always check this
      -- this condition is true if code is null or code isn't 1,
      ((C.code IS NULL or C.code <> 1)
      -- or (if the code is 1), it is true if g.active and d.code
       OR (G.Active = 1 AND D.code = '1'))
```